# ReshSharp — Request returning a different response

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm trying to do a post request from C# .Net app using RestSharp.
But I never got the same response content as in Network Monitor in Mozilla.

Request headers as they appear in Mozilla Network Monitor :

```
        Accept
            text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
        Accept-Encoding
            gzip, deflate, br
        Accept-Language
            en-US,en;q=0.5
        Connection
            keep-alive
        Content-Length
            394
        Content-Type
            application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        Cookie
            __cfduid=d0f7ae06be8ff11d2b9b3522a203fb71b1595168119; __utmzz=utmccn=(not set); _ga=GA1.2.559561681.1595168123; LPVID=liNTFmZTY4Njk1NTU5Nzg2; _gid=GA1.2.1215224234.1595688184; __utmzzses=1; LPSID-52044163=QHW47RmlTOGJRR3WgQPqZQ; mf_2c80a2b7-dd4e-49e6-8cd4-ae5d62e2e0f9=|.47.1595766630775|1595766635857||0|||0|17.20|86.14431; CCauth=ETaZkd-myNz0emeiWobud-xymnYc-gN0v_y_JfZO0KaeM0mQRnhVGzKHZ1sh7pmSLvYHKL_-CSU1TnHRZM_WUfWayst5O1JvTts-GdTC9CZsC2yxWRiaLlofNqJQi8CWI-74PzDTaRBBKs7s8DvJh1oHzmn9oYE_SkBJbtO8OgMZNgnDZFOP…YXBpLlBhcnRuZXJTZXNzaW9uRGV0YWlscwAAAAAAAAABAgALTAALYWNjb3VudE5hbWV0ABJMamF2YS9sYW5nL1N0cmluZztMAAVicmFuZHEAfgABTAAHY2hhbm5lbHEAfgABTAAEZmVJZHEAfgABTAAPZ2xvYmFsU2Vzc2lvbklkcQB%2BAAFMAAZsYW5nSWRxAH4AAUwADHBhcnRuZXJUb2tlbnEAfgABTAAJcGxheWVyVUlEcQB%2BAAFMAAdwcm9kdWN0cQB%2BAAFMABFzZXJ2aWNlU2Vzc2lvbktleXEAfgABTAAGdXNlcklkcQB%2BAAF4cHQAC2NjXzU4MjYwMDQ1dAAKQ0FTSU5PQ0xVQnQAAldDdAACY2NwcHQAGEJTSWI1RFUuRUp6cFdzeXBTMXMzWndfX3B0AAdjYXNoaWVycHQACDU4MjYwMDQ1; BROUTE=ha.bes1; sessionStart=1595766653148; _gat_UA-31388-1=1
        Host
            subdomain.domain.com
        Origin
            subdomain.domain.com
        Referer
            subdomain.domain.com/deposit/Submit.action
        TE
            Trailers
        Upgrade-Insecure-Requests
            1
        User-Agent
            Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
```

Request params :

```
        preference  "MB"
        submitaction    "Submit.action"
        removeFields    ""
        formattedMinTxnLimit    "10.00"
        formattedMaxTxnLimit    "20.00"
        formattedFee    "0.00"
        feeType "abs"
        amount  "10"
        navamount   "10.00"
        userInputAmount "10"
        emailId "mail@provider.com"
        accountIdentifier   "1"
        currency    "USD"
        bonusId "0"
        tncFromBonusService "Y"
        newBonusEnabled "true"
        showBonusQualifyMsg "Y"
        showPaypalBonusMsg  "Y"
        bonuscode   ""
```

My code :

```
            var client = new RestClient("subdomain.domain.com/deposit/Submit.action");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

            request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
            request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            request.AddHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddHeader("Cookie", "__cfduid=d0f7ae06be8ff11d2b9b3522a203fb71b1595168119; __utmzz=utmccn=(not set); _ga=GA1.2.559561681.1595168123; LPVID=liNTFmZTY4Njk1NTU5Nzg2; _gid=GA1.2.1215224234.1595688184; __utmzzses=1; LPSID-52044163=QHW47RmlTOGJRR3WgQPqZQ; mf_2c80a2b7-dd4e-49e6-8cd4-ae5d62e2e0f9=|.47.1595766630775|1595766635857||0|||0|17.20|86.14431; CCauth=ETaZkd-myNz0emeiWobud-xymnYc-gN0v_y_JfZO0KaeM0mQRnhVGzKHZ1sh7pmSLvYHKL_-CSU1TnHRZM_WUfWayst5O1JvTts-GdTC9CZsC2yxWRiaLlofNqJQi8CWI-74PzDTaRBBKs7s8DvJh1oHzmn9oYE_SkBJbtO8OgMZNgnDZFOPiQ9LZLSYijmVcXNhdQ4-QvC4mOjKAWYobnvPbE-8ul9CCz0W5qI-ZFjJMwGYbnLH9WkouezxlMUd7H8MTfm7Gec3mr1XfGamcKMWySRuGgFi7AxLdJmYJFlLB6PMUTXkZiUY25G0rNr1TpIbzBoSMn_K9D452dCVFgVCdM5b2fA6sCXWT5ch_KQWR2-2Af6K1ZdIk9151o2pQcR_0707KgYIXktJoZO6PYgQNpoix5ey8kVmzgZkxg6X2xMnzsHRCwRL9exKn5Qa84lz7NAXKfy1zcFIKPdkTrBade5dKlFxYMfaIVHcuvehbUkaHntRx6lBWLyQ4lnLRC9XqPdcHrEIO7u0vSHE7g; JSESSIONID=6C7DA21036A31D8FC22D91668197435F; sessionKey=rO0ABXNyADVjb20ucGcucGFydG5lci5sb2dpbnNlcnZpY2UuYXBpLlBhcnRuZXJTZXNzaW9uRGV0YWlscwAAAAAAAAABAgALTAALYWNjb3VudE5hbWV0ABJMamF2YS9sYW5nL1N0cmluZztMAAVicmFuZHEAfgABTAAHY2hhbm5lbHEAfgABTAAEZmVJZHEAfgABTAAPZ2xvYmFsU2Vzc2lvbklkcQB%2BAAFMAAZsYW5nSWRxAH4AAUwADHBhcnRuZXJUb2tlbnEAfgABTAAJcGxheWVyVUlEcQB%2BAAFMAAdwcm9kdWN0cQB%2BAAFMABFzZXJ2aWNlU2Vzc2lvbktleXEAfgABTAAGdXNlcklkcQB%2BAAF4cHQAC2NjXzU4MjYwMDQ1dAAKQ0FTSU5PQ0xVQnQAAldDdAACY2NwcHQAGEJTSWI1RFUuRUp6cFdzeXBTMXMzWndfX3B0AAdjYXNoaWVycHQACDU4MjYwMDQ1; BROUTE=ha.bes1; sessionStart=1595766653148; _gat_UA-31388-1=1");
            //request.AddHeader("Host", "subdomain.domain.com");
            request.AddHeader("Origin", "subdomain.domain.com");
            request.AddHeader("Referer", "subdomain.domain.com/deposit/Submit.action");
            request.AddHeader("TE", "Trailers");
            request.AddHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
            request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0");

            request.AddQueryParameter("preference", "MB");
            request.AddQueryParameter("submitaction", "Submit.action");
            request.AddQueryParameter("removeFields", "");
            request.AddQueryParameter("formattedMinTxnLimit ", "10.00");
            request.AddQueryParameter("formattedMaxTxnLimit", "20.00");
            request.AddQueryParameter("formattedFee", "0.00");
            request.AddQueryParameter("feeType", "abs");
            request.AddQueryParameter("amount", "10");
            request.AddQueryParameter("navamount", "10.00");
            request.AddQueryParameter("userInputAmount", "10");
            request.AddQueryParameter("emailId", "mail@provider.com");
            request.AddQueryParameter("accountIdentifier", "1");
            request.AddQueryParameter("currency", "USD");
            request.AddQueryParameter("bonusId", "0");
            request.AddQueryParameter("tncFromBonusService", "Y");
            request.AddQueryParameter("newBonusEnabled", "true");
            request.AddQueryParameter("showBonusQualifyMsg", "Y");
            request.AddQueryParameter("showPaypalBonusMsg", "Y");
            request.AddQueryParameter("bonuscode", "");

            var response = client.Execute(request);
            
            MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
            Clipboard.SetText(response.Content);
```

The response content i get when i execute my code :

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function getCookieValue(key) {
                var value = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*'+ key +'\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
                return value ? value.pop() : '';
            }
            var clientScheme = getCookieValue('clientScheme');
            var url = "";
                url = "www.domain.com";

            if(clientScheme){
                document.location.href= clientScheme+"://?event=navigateToUrl&url="+encodeURIComponent(url);
            } else{
                window.top.location=url;
            }
            </script>
```

The response content i should get :

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <meta name="google" value="notranslate"/>
            <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
            <META NAME="googlebot" CONTENT="noindex, nofollow, noarchive" />
            <meta name="referrer" content="origin-when-crossorigin">
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
            <meta name="description" /> ...
```

I tried the same thing on postman.com (allows you to post requests online for testing stuff..), and it worked.
I have no idea why this happens when I use RestSharp in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Either you are trying to send a POST request (`var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);`) and you need to url-form encode your parameters instead of putting them in the query string, or maybe you mean to send a GET request instead? And therefore you should change the method type to `Method.GET`. Look at your network monitor and observe the request type. If it truly is POST, you might be blocked from performing this action because of a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) policy that restricts access to modifying the resource because the request came from a different origin.